# EnumParentAttribute and Intellisense

Tags: c#, enums

I have a class with an enum

```
namespace Entities
{
    public partial class OrderStatusType : Entity
    {
        public enum EOrderStatusType
        {
            P2 = 1,
            Mounting = 2,
        }
    }
}
```

then I have an interface

```
namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface IAttribute<T>
    {
        T Value { get; }
    }

}
```

and another class

```
namespace Entities
{
    public partial class OrderStatus : Entity
    {
        [DataContract]
        public enum EOrderStatus
        {
            [EnumMember(Value = "Film Ordered"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            FilmOrdered = 1,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Not Started"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            NotStarted = 2,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Cliche Ordered"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            ClicheOrdered = 3,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Cliche In Stock"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            ClicheInStock = 4,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Cliche Prepared"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            ClichePrepared = 5,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Ready to start"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            Readytostart = 6,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Started"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            Started = 7,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Interrupted"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            Interrupted = 8,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Completed"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            Completed = 9,
            [EnumMember(Value = "ClichV status"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            ClichVstatus = 10,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Cliche Mounting"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            ClicheMounting = 11,
            [EnumMember(Value = "In Stock"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.P2)]
            InStock = 12,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Ordine con cilindri montati"), EnumParent(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.Mounting)]
            OrdineConCilindriMontati = 13,
        }

        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
        public sealed class EnumParentAttribute : Attribute, Library.Interfaces.IAttribute<OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType>
        {
            public EnumParentAttribute(OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType EOrderStatusType) { this.mValue = EOrderStatusType; }

            private OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType mValue;

            public OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType Value { get { return mValue; } }
        }
    }
}
```

In class OrderStatus I create a sealed subclass EnumParentAttribute that inherits from attribute and implements the interface and where I can pass a parameter of type OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType, so now I can decorate the items of the enum EOrderStatus with the custom attribute EnumParent, that accept a parameter of type OrderStatusType.EOrderStatusType.

The reason of that is that I want to create a sort of son-parent realtionship between two enums.
But I'd like to take another step or two...

**Question:**

1) How can I add a "constarint" that forces me to decorate a new EOrderStatusType item with the custom attribute EnumParent? There is a way to ask to compiler to notify an exception during compile?
2) How can I extend the EOrderStatusType enum so that I can write a code like this:
    OrderStatus.EOrderStatusType(P2) l_MyEnum = OrderStatus.EOrderStatus.FilmOrdered;
where the Intellisense shows me only the items with the "right" parent?

Sorry for my english, I hope it is quite understandable...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I add a "constarint" that forces me to decorate a new EOrderStatusType item with the custom attribute EnumParent? There is a way to ask to compiler to notify an exception during compile?

Two options:

- Add a unit test. This is dead easy to do, and it'll hopefully stop you from *submitting* bad code (assuming you don't submit without running the tests) but it won't actually show up at compile time.
- Use Visual Studio 2015 and [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.net) to hook into the compiler, and create a code diagnostic that shows this up as an error. (You'd probably want to make it depend on an attribute declared on the enum itself, rather than hard-coding it to one particular enum.) Of course, Visual Studio 2015 is only in preview as I write this - but it will become an increasingly reasonable solution over time.

> How can I extend the EOrderStatusType enum so that I can write a code like this: OrderStatus.EOrderStatusType(P2) l_MyEnum = OrderStatus.EOrderStatus.FilmOrdered;

I don't think you can do this even with Roslyn, to be honest.

As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you ditch the `E` prefix from your enum types. Ick :)